# Boot Windows 10 from a new SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd

I've bought a new SSD and made a fresh windows 10 install. Everything works great with one single problem.

If I shutdown windows and keep the PC off(without power) for about 10-20 minutes, when I start it again, it will remain on the loading sequence ( it will show the windows 10 logo and the animated loading icon under, the one with the small dots moving in circle).
It will stay like this until I press the reset button and after that windows is loading great.

Another weird part is that if I shut down windows, computer turns off, wait like 30sec-1 minute then start it again it works.
This problem happens only if computer is off for a longer period like 20 minutes.

Is this a windows problem and I need to change something in power settings?
Is this a bios settings problem? The SSD has the latest firmware.

I use this SSD on an old desktop computer from 2007 with SATA 2.

**UPDATE**

As requested I provide the energy report

```
Enabling tracing for 60 seconds...
Observing system behavior...
Analyzing trace data...
Analysis complete.

Energy efficiency problems were found.

15 Errors
13 Warnings
14 Informational
```

Full report:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/79qyp95jaxsq77c/energy-report.html?dl=0

**UPDATE 2**

I think I've disabled hybrid sleep and fast startup.
Here is what `powercfg -a` returns

```
powercfg -a
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S1)

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S3)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Hibernate
        Hibernation has not been enabled.

    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Hybrid Sleep
        Standby (S3) is not available.
        Hibernation is not available.

    Fast Startup
        Hibernation is not available.
```

**UPDATE 3**

Even if I have hibernation off the `hiberfil.sys` file is still created [image]

Is there a way to disable the creating of the file? or how can I delete the `hiberfil.sys`? A simple delete is not working

Comment: Run a memory test

Comment: @adampski No memory errors have been detected

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you check your connections to the SSD and make sure you have [mounted it properly inside the rig](http://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=981). I'd also suggest you check if you have any recent BIOS version updates on your computer/motherboard manufacturer's website. It might also be a good idea to swap between the SATA modes for the SSD in BIOS and see if that would improve the SSD's performance.  I'd also try plugging it with a different SATA cable and to a different SATA port. Hope this helps. Keep us posted. :)

Comment: Run `powercfg -energy` and analyze the report. Here are a couple of useful articles: [article1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976034) and [article2](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/). If you find something, let us know, but it would also help to post the entire report.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your comment. I've updated the main post with the energy report.

Comment: disable the fastStart feature and look what happens: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: The errors in the energy report are mostly not serious, but there are a couple of weirdies: (1) The CPU utilization is 46%, it should be nearer to 0% during the test, (2) The BIOS does not support sleep state S3 (which I believe is connected to hybrid sleep). You night try to find if a newer BIOS exists for your computer and maybe also the chipset driver. Let us know your computer model if you wish help.

Comment: Any explanation for the CPU utilization, or information about your computer?

Comment: @harrymc yes, I was archiving something during the test, probably that's why the cpu was that high. it's usually around 3-5%. The PC is custom built: motherboard is asrock 4core1333-viiv with latest bios update, CPU is Intel core 2 duo E6750 2.66Ghz, SSD: Kingston Savage (SHSS37A/240G)

Comment: Per your updates something is weird. Either you're not applying the fixes right, or else your OS install may be hosed... If you want to, boot a windows 10 system repair disk on this computer (your install DVD will work fine) and see if any automatic repairs need to be made.

Comment: Sometimes a Windows installation goes bad, even when new. I would suggest to do [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), ensuring that you have the latest Windows ISO.

Comment: To delete the hiberfil.sys file, try to enter a Command Prompt (cmd) as administrator, then enter `powercfg -h on`, reboot, followed by `powercfg -h off` and another reboot. The file should now be gone, or Windows is in a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

Turn of hybrid sleep and check again. Check this: 
http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=42
Search for Allow hybrid sleep and disable it. Windows 8.x and 10 use hybrid sleep also for shutdown (at start it partially de-hibernate and partially boot system). Probably something are not correctly initialised after that type of resume. Usually it is driver or hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Szczypel's answer will resolve the problem, but of course Hybrid Sleep exists in order to speed up the reloading of windows, so perhaps you want to keep it instead of disabling it. In that case, we need to understand what's happening here. I think I can help with that.

When you are turning off your PC, Windows seems to think it is sending the PC to the S3 power state, but in fact your PC is going directly to fully off. Chances are this issue can be resolved by checking your motherboard's BIOS and making sure that the S3 power state is available and enabled. If it's not even available, then you'll have to disable hybrid sleep in Windows. Per @harrymc, it look like this may unfortunately be the case for your system, barring a BIOS update which changes this capability.

The reason it works if you turn your PC on after just a little time has passed is because the data hasn't yet cleared the RAM. The S3 state saves the current system RAM state at shutdown and keeps power flowing to the DIMMs so that that state is preserved at next boot. You either don't have S3 or S3 isn't enabled, so instead charge is allowed to drain from the RAM, which means that it loses the data stored in it over time. It's actually pretty amazing to me how long it's lasting in your PC before it clears, but I'm fairly sure that's what the behavior must indicate. The clincher is that when you boot next, Windows is looking for that stuff in RAM, but it can't find it - and the boot hangs. On the next boot, Windows 10 has been smart enough to see that it is booting from a full shutdown, and it just goes ahead and loads normally, pulling everything it needs directly from your SSD. Thus when you hit reset, the second boot works!

The reason I doubt Szczypel's concern about the possibility of a driver improperly initializing (definitely another possibility, but I think an unlikely one) is because you've just done a fresh install. There are not likely very many dodgy drivers on your system yet, so I wouldn't look to that as the first probable source of the trouble.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your post, but I've did this in cmd: powercfg -h off  and the problem is still there.

Comment: I also check registry and HiberbootEnables is 0: http://image.prntscr.com/image/4ab16a038c844b969883a5362d1ae2ef.png

Comment: Have you gone into your BIOS yet to determine what, if any, power or boot-related settings might be found there? I realize that hibernation is turned off per your checks, but what I'm talking about isn't actually Hibernation; it's Fast Boot or Hybrid Sleep, I forget which. Tomasz Szczypel calls it Hybrid Sleep, so maybe he's got the name right. Hibernation saves an image of system state to disk, while Fast Boot takes the much riskier proposition of saving to RAM, which is volatile storage. You need to check for S3 settings.

Comment: I've updated main post (UPDATE 2) with more info. I've checked BIOS and I didn't see any S3 power options.

Comment: @DouaBeri per your manual chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/4Core1333-Viiv.pdf on page 58 I believe the S3 power state is labeled "Suspend to RAM" in your old BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a newer SSD & OS with an old system that doesn't fully support them. Even the motherboard drivers are for Vista and XP. So, this is another issue (which may be solved in most cases).

However, from the energy report you posted, it seems only S1 and S4 sleep states are available on your system. So, I wouldn't suggest using S1 mode over S4. You could use S4 (hibernate) but not a %100 sure that will work flawlessly with your system.

In this case, I see it'll be better to re-check things, so we can resolve this issue. So, try to follow these steps to check settings first.

**First BIOS settings**

Enter BIOS, then check/modify the Advanced settings as listed below:

On the Advanced screen:

- CPU Configuration > Enhance Halt State > **Disabled**
- CPU Configuration > Intel SpeedStep > **Disabled**
- IDE Configuration > SATAII Configuration > **Enhanced**
- IDE Configuration > SATAII Configuration > Configure SATAII as > **AHCI**
- IDE Configuration > SATAII Configuration > OnBoard SATAII Controller > **Enhanced**

Then **Save** & **Exit**.

**Secondly, Windows:**

**Drivers:** I assume that you've downloaded and installed all required drivers. IF NOT, you need to use Driver Solutions or Driver Booster and Install & update all drivers. (Make sure that you do not have any unknown devices using Devices Manager.)

**Windows Updates:** Check and update your system, make sure that you don't have any pending.

**Power Options:**
Go to Power Options screen

1. On the left side, click on *`Choose what the power buttons do`*
2. Now, click on *`Change settings that are currently unavailable`*
3. Change *When I press the power button* to  `Shut down`
4. Change *When I press the sleep button* to `Shut down`
5. Under Shutdown settings Untick *Sleep* & *Hibernate*

SAVE CHANGES

Now restart your system and check.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a new Samsung SSD. I was able to fix it by using a windows recovery disk and running the "Startup Repair" feature. At one point I think that a Widows update was causing the issue because the problem would come back after a few days. Bear in mind that this was very shortly after I installed windows 10 from scratch for the first time. After 4 instances of me running the startup repair and I finally got completely current with my windows updates and the problem went away.

I would try making sure you are completely up to date and then trying the startup repair if you have problems, if for no other reason, do it to rule some stuff out.